# Combining a few methods into the only one. Generics

Tags: java, generics, refactoring

I have some code to figure out the correctness of manipulations on different data types (int, long, double)  comparing to BigInteger. The manipulation is getting a factorial of a number until the result is the same as BigInteger has.

The question is how could i change my code, make more generic, compact and clean? How could i get the only one method, not 4 for different types?
The logic in this methods is pretty the same as well as the flow.

The code (*without comparing logic*) is:

```
private static HashMap<BigInteger, BigInteger> bigIntegerFactorials = new HashMap<>();
private static BigInteger bigIntegerFactorial(BigInteger number) {
    if (number.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    BigInteger result = bigIntegerFactorials.get(number);
    if (result == null) {
        result = number.multiply(bigIntegerFactorial(number.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
        bigIntegerFactorials.put(number, result);
    }
    return result;
}

private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> intFactorials = new HashMap<>();
private static int intFactorial(int number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    Integer result = intFactorials.get(number);
    if (result == null) {
        result = number * intFactorial(number - 1);
        intFactorials.put(number, result);
    }
    return result;
}

private static HashMap<Long, Long> longFactorials = new HashMap<>();
private static long longFactorial(long number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        return 1L;
    }
    Long result = longFactorials.get(number);
    if (result == null) {
        result = number * longFactorial(number - 1);
        longFactorials.put(number, result);
    }
    return result;
}

private static HashMap<Double, Double> doubleFactorials = new HashMap<>();
private static double doubleFactorial(double number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        return 1.;
    }
    Double result = doubleFactorials.get(number);
    if (result == null) {
        result = number * doubleFactorial(number - 1);
        doubleFactorials.put(number, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: My advice would be to look at a case statement (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) if you really want it in one method. Sometimes different methods with unique (and readable) names are what's best for clean code :)

Comment: One option would be to have a `factorial(Number n)` but you would not be able to easily write this line `result = number * longFactorial(number - 1);` because there is no operator overloading in Java...

Comment: Is it possible for you to use java 8? If yes, then you can easily achieve this by creating a generic method that will accept corresponding lambda functions (like multiplication), and then just specify these functions for each case.

Comment: @assylias yes, thats right about operator overloading, i tried a lot of approaches `factorial(Number n)` one of them. I actually have a fealing of something wrong in my code because of a lot mostly the same lines in my code. @Gorb u r right about sometimes. I want to know is it this time now also if possible. Thanks guys for topic attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the multiply and decrement functions to a generic method:

```
private static Map<Number, Number> factorials = new HashMap<> ();

private static <T extends Number> T factorial(T n, BinaryOperator<T> multiply, UnaryOperator<T> decrement) {
  if (n.doubleValue() == 1) return n;
  T result = (T) factorials.get(n);
  if (result == null ){
    result = multiply.apply(n, factorial(decrement.apply(n), multiply, decrement));
    factorials.put(n, result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Then you can change your primitive methods like so:

```
public static int intFactorial(int number) {
  return factorial(number, (i, j) -> i * j, i -> i - 1);
}
```

WARNING: this method seems to crash Netbeans but compiles fine with javac...

Comment: It looks very good. I used it in my code. Very great trick with operators. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really trying to compute a factorial, then there isn't any need for `double` or `BigDouble` since [factorial only applies to integer values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).  And since that's true, you can convert any integer type to `BigInteger` and go with a single method that takes any `Number` returns `BigInteger`.

Here's a test class

```
public class Junk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long val = 9;
        Junk j = new Junk();
        System.out.println(val + "! = " + j.factorial(val));
        BigInteger nine = new BigInteger("9");
        System.out.println(nine + "! = " + j.factorial(nine));
        short nine_short = 9;
        System.out.println(nine_short + "! = " + j.factorial(nine_short));
    }

    private HashMap<BigInteger, BigInteger> map = new HashMap<>();


    public BigInteger factorial(Number number){
        if(1 == number.intValue()){
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        }

        BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(number.toString());
        BigInteger result = map.get(bigInteger);

        if(result == null){
            result = bigInteger.multiply(factorial(bigInteger.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
            map.put(bigInteger,result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And the output

```
9! = 362880
9! = 362880
9! = 362880
```

Comment: `BigInteger.ONE.equals(number)` will only return true if number is a BigInteger...

Comment: @assylias Ooops.  Fixed.

Comment: @MadConan Maybe my question was not clear enough, sorry for that, but the idea is to show the corectness of different data types of dipicting factorials. For example if we use short we cant get 9! = 362880, because it is out of 16-bit range of twos complement integer. The result of short will be failed a bit earlier. I use BigInteger to always know the right result of any factorial. And I compare the result of `bigIntegerFactorials()` to others and so i can see where different data types fail.  Thanks for your answer, but if the task were to find any factorial i would take your logic.

Comment: @zds I guess I misinterpreted your question.